Plotly figure with subplots and dropdown hides second plot when non-default option selected
I am trying to generate a Plotly figure with two sub plots and has dropdown menu. The default option works fine (Fig. 1) but when other values are selected the second plot disappears (Fig. 2). How to fix this issue such that for all options selected the second plot and legend appears?

Fig. 1

Fig. 2
MWE
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
np.random.seed(42)

data = {
'Value1': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value2': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value3': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value4': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value5': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value6': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1, vertical_spacing = 0.1, shared_xaxes = True)
for r in df.columns[2:-1]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Value1'], y = df[r], mode ='markers', marker_symbol = 'circle', visible = False), row = 1, col = 1, secondary_y = False)
fig.data[0].visible = True
dropdown_buttons = [{'label': column, 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [col == column for col in df.columns[2:-1]]}]} for column in df.columns[2:-1]]
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Value1'], y = df['Value2'], mode = 'markers', visible = True), row = 2, col = 1, secondary_y = False)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text = 'Value1', row = 2, col = 1)
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[{'buttons': dropdown_buttons, 'direction': 'down', 'showactive': False}], \
template = 'plotly')
fig.write_html('plot.html')


What is the column of the data frame that you want the intended output to be displayed in the 'value3' button? Likewise, what are the columns selected for 'value4' and 'value5'? When you run print(len(fig.data)), how many graphs do you want to see? Do you want to see `6'?Your code would result in 3 graphs in row 1 and 1 graph in row 2.

I only need one column/trace in each plot. The bottom plot is a fixed column 'Value2' always. On the top plot I need the option to chose any columns between Value3 to Value6. The problem is when I change to Value6 from Value3 the bottom trace disappears.

The code in question has broken indentation and I can't pinpoint the cause, but if the bottom graph is fixed at 'value2', you could add a second graph process in the loop process.

I fixed the code.

You have four traces total (three traces that alternate between value3, value4, value5 in the first subplot, and one trace for value2 that is always visible in the second subplot), so you need to add [True] to your visible list to force the value2 to show in the second subplot.
The buttons for value3, value4, value5 should correspond to [True, False, False, True], [False, True, False, True], [False, False, True, True]
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
np.random.seed(42)

data = {
'Value1': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value2': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value3': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value4': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value5': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
'Value6': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1, vertical_spacing = 0.1, shared_xaxes = True)
for r in df.columns[2:-1]:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Value1'], y = df[r], name=r, mode ='markers', marker_symbol = 'circle', visible = False,), row = 1, col = 1, secondary_y = False)
fig.data[0].visible = True
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Value1'], y = df['Value2'], name='Value2', mode = 'markers', visible = False,), row = 2, col = 1, secondary_y = False)

## make the last trace visible when the plot loads initially
fig.data[-1].visible = True

## hardcode the visible list to have an additional [True]
dropdown_buttons = [{'label': column, 'method': 'update', 'args': [{'visible': [col == column for col in df.columns[2:-1]] + [True]}]} for column in df.columns[2:-1]]
fig.update_xaxes(title_text = 'Value1', row = 2, col = 1)
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[{'buttons': dropdown_buttons, 'direction': 'down', 'showactive': False}], \
template = 'plotly')
fig.show()


